# Binding on inherited Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have an attached property that's inheritable:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourcePackageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ResourcePackage", typeof(IResourcePackage), typeof(ResourceUIElement),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

On a container control, I set this attached property => the descendent controls inherit this which is fine so far.

Now I try to define a binding like this:

```
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = proxy;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(childControl, ResourceUIElement.ResourcePackageProperty, binding);
```

This is supposed to update the *Value*-property of the *proxy*-object when the ResourcePackage-property of the *childControl* changes.

This works when I directly set the attached property on the child control, but it **doesn't** work when the attached property is changed on the container control (and thus, is inherited to *childControl*).

Is this possible at all with WPF's Dependency Property system?

Comment: Please note that you don't set bindings on complete classes, but on instances. So if you want your proxy-Value to change if the AP in your container control is changed, you need to set another binding with your container control as target.

Comment: I understood it like this:
the childControl-instance derives the AP from the containercontrol-instance => thus, I supposed that changing the AP on the containercontrol changes it on the child controls as well (because they derive it) and bindings will be triggered.

If that's not the case, I can't do anything against it - the code that creates the binding doesn't know which ancestor-control has the AP set.

Comment: Through deriving your just "copying" the classes methods, props, etc, but the instances you build out of these classes are not connected. So changing a property on an instance of the base class has no effect to the instances of the derived classes. But let me tell you: there is always a way, don't give up ;) You could, f.e., add a property called ContainerControl to you childControl, which gets set when a child control gets added to the container control.

Comment: I dont understand the question. Can you post more code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the solution:

```
var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = childControl;
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("(0)", ResourceUIElement.ResourcePackageProperty);
binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(proxy, Proxy.ValueProperty, binding);
```

Turning the binding into the opposite direction works. Previously it was OneWayToSource, now the Proxy-class is derived from DependencyObject and the binding is OneWay.